# Librería .so no carga con ctypes en python usando raspberry

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, librería

Tengo una librería llamada `ldesfire.v1.0.so` con la extensión .so y al momento de importar esta librería de la siguiente forma en python:

`libreria_rfid = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('ldesfire.v1.1.so')`

Me marca este error.

[image: Error]

Este es el script completo:

```
import ctypes
import time

l = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('ldesfire.v1.1.so')

if l.isCardPresent():
    print("Tarjeta presente")
else:
    print("Tarjeta no presente")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Estoy utilizando una raspberry pi4, intente en el software bullseye y buster. Y en ninguno tuve exito.

De igual manera intente llamar la librería de esta forma y tampoco me funcionó:

```
libreria_rfid = ctypes.cdll('ldesfire.v1.1.so')
```

Comment: ¿ Esa librería corresponde a tu plataforma ? Reformulado: ¿ La has bajado/copiado tu manualmente, o de donde ha salido ?

Comment: Esta pregunta pertenece al sitio de server fault, esta relacionada a la libreria que implementas y no es acorde al S.O

Comment: La libreria me la entregaron a mí en una carpeta, y de ella debo yo acceder a su contenido desde python, pero me da ese error.

Comment: Dado que lo estás preguntando, entiendo que no tienes muy claros temas sobre arquitectura de máquina y similares. Resumiendo: **no puedes**. Esa librería no se puede ejecutar sobre una Raspberry.

Comment: Si, claro que se puede ejecutar esa librería en una Raspberry, ya existe un software desarrollado que utiliza esa librería en una rasp utilizando python. Claramente no tengo acceso a ese código en python, es por eso que busco la manera de acceder a las propiedades que tiene el archivo .so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El inconveniente era que no tenia una libreria de nfc instalada en mi raspberry. Y esa librería nfc la utiliza el archivo .so